# Creating multiple ROI on webcam video

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, roi

Im trying to create multiple ROIs over my webcam stream. Ive used this library called roipoly (https://github.com/jdoepfert/roipoly.py)

I modified the example code (examples/multi_roi_example.py) to work on webcam , which now looks like this

```
import logging
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from roipoly import MultiRoi

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s ''%(processName)-10s : %(asctime)s '
                           '%(module)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while cap.isOpened():

# Create image
    val,img =cap.read()

#img = np.ones((100, 100)) * range(0, 100)

# Show the image
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
    plt.title("Click on the button to add a new ROI")

# Draw multiple ROIs
    multiroi_named = MultiRoi(roi_names=['My first ROI', 'My second ROI'])

# Draw all ROIs
    plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
    roi_names = []
    for name, roi in multiroi_named.rois.items():
        roi.display_roi()
        roi.display_mean(img)
        roi_names.append(name)
    plt.legend(roi_names, bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.05))
    plt.show()
    # Let OpenCV manage window events
    key = cv2.waitKey(50)
    # If ESCAPE key pressed, stop
    if key == 27:
        cap.release()
```

But the issue is that after drawing the ROI, the video stream remains paused and never continues. How to resume the webcam stream along with the ROI on top of it

Comment: `plt.show()` is not part of `cv2` and it may block it. Maybe better use `cv2.imshow("name", img)` to display video (and draw `cv2.rectange()` on every frame to show `ROI`). Shortly: i would remove all `matplotlib` functions and use only cv2 functions.

Comment: you may need also some boolean variable to skip multiroi in next loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few problems.

Main problem is that `plt.show()` is waiting until you close window and this is blocking rest of code.

It needs `plt.show(block=False)` and this needs also `plt.pause(0.001)` so it would have time to update image in window.

```
    plt.show(block=False)    
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

Other problem is that you run ROI in every loop - so you would have to use some boolean variable to skip it after selecting

```
select_roi = True

while cap.isOpened():

    # ... code ...

    if select_roi:
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
        plt.title("Click on the button to add a new ROI")

        # Draw multiple ROIs
        multiroi_named = MultiRoi(roi_names=['My first ROI', 'My second ROI'])
        
        select_roi = False  

    # ... code ...
```

or you should select ROI before loop

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
plt.title("Click on the button to add a new ROI")

# Draw multiple ROIs
multiroi_named = MultiRoi(roi_names=['My first ROI', 'My second ROI'])

while cap.isOpened():

     # ... code ...
```

---

Other problem is `waitKey` which works only if you display image with `cv2.imshow(...)` but you don't use it so `waitKey` will not get keys.

Other problem is that cv2 gives image in colors `BGR` but `matplotlib` needs `RGB` - so you have to convert it.

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

---

Full working code:

version with boolean variable `select_roi`

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from roipoly import MultiRoi

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # my built-in webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

select_roi = True   # default value as start

while cap.isOpened():

    val, img = cap.read()

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    if select_roi:
        # Show the image
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
        plt.title("Click on the button to add a new ROI")

        # Draw multiple ROIs
        multiroi_named = MultiRoi(roi_names=['My first ROI', 'My second ROI'])
        
        select_roi = False
   
    # --- after if ---
 
    # Draw all ROIs
    plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
    
    roi_names = []
    for name, roi in multiroi_named.rois.items():
        roi.display_roi()
        #roi.display_mean(img)
        roi_names.append(name)
        
    plt.legend(roi_names, bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.05))
    plt.show(block=False)    
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

version with ROI before loop

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from roipoly import MultiRoi

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # my built-in webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

val, img = cap.read()

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Show the image
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
plt.title("Click on the button to add a new ROI")

# Draw multiple ROIs
multiroi_named = MultiRoi(roi_names=['My first ROI', 'My second ROI'])

while cap.isOpened():

    val, img = cap.read()

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Draw all ROIs
    plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', cmap="Greys")
    
    roi_names = []
    for name, roi in multiroi_named.rois.items():
        roi.display_roi()
        #roi.display_mean(img)
        roi_names.append(name)
        
    plt.legend(roi_names, bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.05))
    plt.show(block=False)    
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

---

**BTW:** if you need rectangle ROI then there is `cv2.selectROI()` to select one region and `cv2.cv2.selectROIs()` to select many regions

```
results = cv2.selectROIs('image', img)
```

and it doesn't need to convert from `BGR` to `RGB`.